# SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql-server

All,

I am trying out a new linked server - I can run this command fine:

```
SELECT * FROM NextGen4.NGEPMWareHouse.dbo.Network_People
```

If I try to get fancy (update a table on my local server from the linked server)

```
UPDATE dbo.Network_People
SET dbo.Network_People.NGTimeStamp = NextGen4.NGEPMWareHouse.dbo.Network_People.[TimeStamp]
WHERE dbo.Network_People.HIN = NextGen4.NGEPMWareHouse.dbo.Network_People.HIN
```

I get

The number name 'NextGen4.NGEPMWareHouse.dbo.Network_People' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try woking with `UPDATE … FROM` and an alias.

```
UPDATE 
  dbo.Network_People
SET 
  NGTimeStamp = warehouse.[TimeStamp]
FROM
  NextGen4.NGEPMWareHouse.dbo.Network_People AS warehouse
  INNER JOIN dbo.Network_People AS people ON people.HIN = warehouse.HIN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude ".dbo" prefix from your tablenames and use "update from"